# how to disable automatic brightness ubuntu 22.04

Tags: power-management, brightness, 22.04, settings, automatic

I'm using ubuntu 22.04. It automaticly changes the brightness. In setting, my device has not the automatic brightness option. I realized that's hardware dependent. Even so my screen changes it’s brightness randomly as if it was enabled. Although not often but it is very inhibited. Someone can help me.

Comment: I presume you looked in settings - power - power saving - and checked the toggle for automatic brightness is off? If so, and your screen is still changing  brightness automatically, I think it might be outside the os.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, the solution was to disable the "Automatic Screen Brightness" option.

Go to: Settings -> Power -> in the section "Power Saving Options" you will find the "Automatic Screen Brightness" option.

Comment: Ubuntu 22 doesn't seem to have this setting.

Comment: Thank you. That helped on Pop_OS running over Ubuntu 22.04 as well.

Answer (score 1):

@LP had the correct solution for me on 22.04.2. @Wajahath should be there.

You an also bring it up from the command line by first checking to see if the power option is there:

```
gnome-control-center -l
gnome-control-center -s power
```

For Mate users:

```
mate-control-center
```

For Cinnamon users:

```
cinnamon-settings
```

For Unity users:

```
unity-control-center
```

[Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ziaI.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Dell Latitude 7430 laptop connected to an external screen - Philips 346B. Brightness used to go up and down depending on the content displayed on the screen (darker picture - lower brightness, lighter picture - higher brightness). The "Automatic Screen Brightness" option was missing in the settings.

Turned out that I always had my laptop's lid closed and only used the external monitor. Once I opened the lid, the option appeared in settings and I was able to turn it off. I then closed the lid again - and the auto-brightness was back on, and the settings options was gone again. Then I looked at the monitor settings (it's a pretty hi-end one) - and found out there was a light sensor which was turned off. I turned it on, re-opened Settings, and the "Automatic Screen Brightness" option was back there, for me to turn it off.

Not sure how this is implemented but it occurs to me that at least certain options may be saved for each device separately.

Oh, and before I had the settings option back, I tried to manually adjust the setting that I found on the internet while searching for this problem: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false`. If you explore power settings with `dconf-editor`, you'll find out that this settings, indeed, exists, and is affected by this command line. Unfortunately, changing it didn't affect the observed behavior, from which I figure that there should be some other relevant settings.